# Return Spring Batch job information as XML

Tags: xml, request, spring-batch, response

When I make a request I want to get back some information as xml. Here is an example of some code I have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/batch/xml/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/xml")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getXML() {
        return xml here;
    }
}
```

I'd like to return the job name, job execution id, and the job status as XML.

I tried searching but couldn't find anything related to my topic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what u have tried so far? You can queries spring batch information from spring_batch tables such as batch_job_instance, batch_job_execution, ....

Comment: I was trying to call JobExecution or a listener but I don't think that's the right approach. I'll look into querying the tables. Thank you @NghiaDo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my issue. The code is below.  The controller calls a service to parse the information then formats the output to XML.

**Controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/batch/{progName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<JobResults> process(@PathVariable("progName") String progName,
                                                        @RequestHeader("Content-Type") MediaType contentType,
                                                        @RequestHeader("Accept") List<MediaType> accept) throws Exception {
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = MccControllerUtils.createCacheDisabledHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        if(!contentType.toString().equals("*/*") && !accept.toString().equals("*/*")) {
            responseHeaders.setContentType(contentType);
            responseHeaders.setAccept(accept);
        }
        LOGGER.info("Running batch program " + progName);
        JobResults response = batchService.processProgName(progName);
        return new ResponseEntity<JobResults>(response, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**Service**

```
 @Override
    public JobResults processProgName(String progName) throws Exception {

        String jobName = "call" + progName.toUpperCase() + "Job";
        JobExecution jobExecution = null;
        String result = "";
        Long jobId = null;
        JobResults results = new JobResults();
        BatchStatus jobStatus = null;
        try {
            // Launch the appropriate batch job.
            Map<String, Job> jobs = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Job.class);
            LOGGER.info("BATCHSTART:Starting sync batch job:" + jobName);
            JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
            // Pass in the runtime to ensure a fresh execution.
            builder.addDate("Runtime", new Date());
            jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(jobs.get(jobName), builder.toJobParameters());
            jobId = jobExecution.getId();
            jobStatus = jobExecution.getStatus();
            results.setName(jobName);
            results.setId(jobId);
            results.setMessage("The job has finished.");
            results.setStatus(jobStatus);
            LOGGER.info("The job ID is " + jobId);
            LOGGER.info("BATCHEND:Completed sync batch job:" + jobName);
            LOGGER.info("Completion status for batch job " + jobName + " is " + jobExecution.getStatus().name());
            List<Throwable> failures = jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions();
            if (failures.isEmpty()) {
                result = jobExecution.getExecutionContext().getString(AbstractSetupTasklet.BATCH_PROGRAM_RESULT);
            } else {
                for (Throwable fail : failures) {
                    result += fail.getMessage() + "\n";
                }
            }
            LOGGER.info("The job results are: " + result);
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("An error occurred while attempting to execute a job. " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return results;
    }
```